# Regular Expression to parse term out of URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm in need of a regular express that will parse the first directory of a URL:

www.mydomain.com/**find_this**/anything/anything..

So -- I wasn't sure how to structure a regex to grab the string containing that first directory, any help appreciated.

Edit -- parsing is not an option, I am trying to create a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = "www.mydomain.com/find_this/anything/anything"; 
path = /(?:http\:\/\/)?(?:www)?\.mydomain\.com\/([^\/]+)/.exec(str) [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
var myString = "www.mydomain.com/find_this/anything/blah"
var string_I_want = myString.replace(/\/\//g, "").split("/")[1]
```

Much easier to read.

Comment: I'm looking for regular express for a specific reason. No parsing.

Comment: @Atticus this is a clever answer, and you should show what you have tried.

Comment: looking for regular expression to use in .htaccess?

Comment: This is what I would do if I wasn't looking for a regular expression. Unfortunately the system my client uses examines an incoming link by regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff matched by the first capturing group (raw regex):

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:\w+)(\.\w+)*(?:\:\d+)/([^/]+)
```

Matches optional `http://`/`https://`, webserver/ip/port, then, the first group is what you want.

```
var url = 'www.mydomain.com/find_this/anything/anything';
var match = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+)(\.\w+)*(?:\:\d+)\/([^\/]+)/.exec(url);
var root = match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

With capture:

```
/(.*?)/
```

With named capture:

```
/(?<first_directory>.*?)/
```

With protocol and capture:

```
(?:https?://.*?)?/(.*?)/
```

With protocol and named capture:

```
(?:https?://.*?)?/(?<first_directory>.*?)/
```

You'll just need to translate for your flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following:

```
var rootDir = location.pathname.replace(/(^\/\w+\/).*/,"$1");
```

Comment: This works if you're needing the first directory from the current browser location.